# Upstart conf changes do not reload after edit

Tags: upstart

After I make some changes to an upstart conf file upstart does not reload the new changes until I reboot the system

```
start on filesystem or runlevel [23]
stop on runlevel [6] 

respawn 
expect fork 

script 
    echo "Starting gunicorn.." > /tmp/upstart_t 
    exec /srv/sms/mwav_messenger/gunicorn_start.sh 
end script 

console output
```

If I was to alter this script I would continue to get the original behaviour. Further to this if I stop or start the script manually the commandline simply hangs and I need to control-c to get back to the commandline.

Cheers.

Answer (score 16):

Changes to Upstart scripts apply when all running instances of that job have stopped. Thus modifying a conf file and doing `sudo restart job` will run it with old values. You need to `sudo stop job`, then `sudo start job` to have new conf file in effect.

Bonus: `sudo stop job` getting stuck at such script means you have wrong `expect` stanza defined. See [Cookbook section on expect](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#expect) for more info on this. tl;dr, likely it is extra and can be removed.

Comment: This terrible! Why isn't restart == stop/start ? Reload is usually for a quick restart.